# How can i listen the BACK keydown in MaintabActivity (contains 2 sub tabActivities)

Tags: android, android-tabhost, keydown

public class MyTab extends TabActivity;

public class SubTab extends TabActivity;

> There is 2 tab defined in MyTab :
>
> 1. setContent(new Intent(this, SubTab.class))
> 2. setContent(R.id.view1)

Then write a method in MyTab :

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
        Log.i("MyTab Back", "In MyTab ");
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

and the method in SubTab ，just change to Log.i("SubTab Back", "In SubTab ").

Problem:
Press Back Key in SubTab,Only "In SubTab" is shown in Logcat.

**Delete the method in SubTab,then press Back Key nothing is shown in Logcat.**

Press Back Key in another tab (not Activity), Only "In MyTab" is shown in Logcat.

NOW, I want to just write a method to listen Back Keydown in MyTab, because of in another project, the mainTab have more than 3 subtabActivity 。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        Log.i("MyTab Back", "In MyTab ");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try the following:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        Log.i("MyTab Back", "In MyTab ");
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```